# new number errors with old number reference

Tags: twilio-api

new to Twilio, just doing a simple js send sms.
had a test number, got everything working, and approved for deployment.
Then I canceled my test number and got our first production number. and updated all the auth info.

and everything stopped working.

We get this - but can't find any docs on this. how to fix it. and Twilio tech support isn't responding.

```
error: Exception: Request failed for https://api.twilio.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"code": 21606, "message": "The From phone number +1866OLDNUMBER is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account.", "... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

any push in the right direction is appreciated.

reset all scripts or setup thinking something is referencing the old number. nothing changed the error.

Comment: Is it possible that your new number is missing the [10 DLC registration](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/1260800720410-What-is-A2P-10DLC-)?